# How to redirect specific pages to http

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect link like this

> http://example.com/log to https://example.com/log and the and other like
>   (log/reg/info)

and those that do not appear in parentheses above:

> example: https://example.com/different to  http://example.com/different

Is there any way to do this using .htaccess?

Comment: You tagged this as .htaccess, but you didn't explicitly mention this in your question. You are asking about how to create redirects in .htacess?

Comment: yes, I mean redirects in htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(log|reg|info)[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(log|reg|info)[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```